# Plot a wordcloud using a dictionary of frequencies

Tags: python, plot, word-cloud

I want to plot a word cloud like this :

[image: example wordcloud]

I have a dictionary of word counts :

```py
dic = {word1:14, word2:242, word3:343}
```

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [word cloud](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud) library for this. It can also be used from the commandline and you would obviously need to look at the documentation to make it give your desired output.

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43954114/2570277) for an example, or this example from the site:

```
Minimal Example
===============
Generating a square wordcloud from the US constitution using default arguments.
"""

import os

from os import path
from wordcloud import WordCloud

# get data directory (using getcwd() is needed to support running example in generated IPython notebook)
d = path.dirname(__file__) if "__file__" in locals() else os.getcwd()

# Read the whole text.
text = open(path.join(d, 'constitution.txt')).read()

# Generate a word cloud image
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)

# Display the generated image:
# the matplotlib way:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")

# lower max_font_size
wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40).generate(text)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()

# The pil way (if you don't have matplotlib)
# image = wordcloud.to_image()
# image.show()
```

Comment: I already looked at it, but it used the text not a dictionnary of frequencies